# Is it possible to create a PDF of a webpage's print view?

Tags: php, css, pdf, printing, download

I have a webpage with a separate stylesheet for print. When I view the print preview it looks exactly how i want it.

Is there a way I can generate a PDF and begin download on click / submit that is that file?

Comment: Btw, i dont mean a button that will launch the print view on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Generate PDF in PHP , you can use FPDF . Gothrough the folowing link to learn more about fpdf

```
http://www.fpdf.org/
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there not a way I can take the 'print' view and convert that to pdf? Without having to design a specific pdf for print?

Answer (score 0):

You can print your webpage using [freepdf](http://freepdfxp.de/) as pdf.

Comment: Ah but i need to do it from within the website.

Comment: Freepdf is an PDF printer you have to install on your computer. Than you can print the webpage as PDF on Print Preview Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like wkhtmltopdf, which converts HTML to PDF format. You'll need to read your own site in, possibly over http, and save a copy to disk before sending out to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of:

> http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/
>   http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/
>   http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

The first two are runnable directly from PHP, suggested if you do not have a Linux server where you can run shell commands. The last one is the best HTML->PDF converter, but it's not a PHP function, it's a Linux shell command. You can run it from PHP if your server allows it.